# How do I use ggplot2 to create a border around a group of US counties?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am relatively new to using R and I am trying to create maps of US states using data to outline and colour certain areas. I am trying to display a state and its counties outlined in black. On top of this, I would like to create thick red borders around groups of counties and colour-fill some counties based on some data I have.

Essentially I want to combine these two images:

[I would like to changed this map to outlines of the coloured areas, so -for example - there would be a red border around everything blue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfxjW.png)

[Then I would like to fill the map above like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mE1yx.png)

This is the code I have written so far attempting this task:

```
# Maping IA, plan 74406IA0010001

# Importing data 
library(ggplot2) 
library(ggmap) 
library(maps) 
library(mapdata) 
library(stringr) 
library(plyr) 
library(dplyr)

setwd("/Users/erinmay/Desktop/WL_RA/marketplace2/data")

county <- map_data("county") 
plan <- read.csv("IA_2017.csv")

# Using subset

iowa <- subset(county, region=="iowa") #county point files for iowa
```

---

```
# Merging in map data

countyplan <- merge(x=iowa, y=plan, by=c("region","subregion"), all.x=TRUE)

countyplan <- countyplan[order(countyplan$chosen_plan),]
```

---

```
# Creating map  

final <- ggplot(data=countyplan) + 
           geom_path(aes(x=long,y=lat,group=RatingArea),colour='black') +  
           geom_polygon(aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group,fill=chosen_plan)) + 
           coord_map() + coord_fixed(1.3)

ggsave(final,height=6,width=10,unit='in',file='iowa.pdf')
```

Thank you in advanced for your help!

Here is the data:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/x8x2l50dvmg0lsb/QHP_IA_2017.csv?dl=0

Comment: Can we have some sample data? It would help with testing solutions. See [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) & [reproducible example in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: The link to example data is broken.  Does anyone have the data or a sample at least?

Answer (score 1):

Edited answer based on OP's clarification to only colour the **outer** borders of each rating area:

As far as I understand it, all polygons are created equal where ggplot is concerned. Hence if it has to colour the outline of a polygon, it will do so for all sides, regardless whether two adjacent polygons belong to the same rating area.

You'll have the dissolve polygons in the same planning area, *before* fortifying them into a data frame. (Note: you can convert the existing data frame back to polygon, but it's probably easier to get polygon data from the original data source.)

```
library(maps); library(dplyr); library(tidyr); library(maptools); library(rgeos)

# get map data
county_map <- map("county", fill = T, plot = FALSE)

# create mapping table between county names & rating areas
county_map_match <- data.frame(name = county_map$names) %>%
  separate(name, c("region", "subregion"), sep = ",", remove = FALSE) %>%
  left_join(plan %>% select(region, subregion, RatingArea))
rownames(county_map_match) <- county_map_match$name

# convert map to SpatialPolygon, then join with mapping table for SpatialPolygonDataFrame
county_map <- map2SpatialPolygons(county_map, IDs = county_map$names)
county_map <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(county_map, county_map_match)

# remove invalidities in the county map
gIsValid(county_map) #returns FALSE: there are invalid self-intersecting geometries in the polygons, which will cause problems
county_map <- gBuffer(county_map, byid = TRUE, width = 0)
gIsValid(county_map) #returns TRUE

# dissolve county map by rating area & fortify to data frame
area_map <- unionSpatialPolygons(county_map, IDs = county_map$RatingArea)
area_map <- fortify(area_map)
area_map$group <- gsub(".1", "", x= area_map$group, fixed = T)
```

Once you obtain the data frame version for rating areas, you can incorporate it into the ggplot:

```
ggplot(countyplan,
       aes(x=long,y=lat, group = group, fill = chosen_plan)) + 
  geom_polygon(size = 0.5, colour = "black") +
  geom_polygon(data = area_map, 
            aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group, colour = group), 
            fill = NA, size = 2) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Chosen Plan", values = c("darksalmon"), na.value = "grey") +
  scale_color_discrete(name = "Rating Area") +
  coord_map() + coord_fixed(1.3)
```

[image: edited ggplot with outer borders coloured]

You can get nicer color palettes from the `RColorBrewer` package & use them in the `scale_XX_brewer()` call, if you like. Names for individual colors can be referenced here: http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/colour

Comment: Almost! This is very helpful, so thank you very much. Is there a way to change the interior lines of a Rating Area to black and just leave the outer borders of the Rating Area coloured?

Comment: @Erin Edited my solution.

Comment: This worked for me. For anyone trying to map their dissolved polygons onto a usmap() (which uses UTM coordinates and AEA projection) you need to run this before plotting: 
area_map <- usmap_transform(data=area_map, input_names=c("long", "lat"))
Then plot the data with 
plot_usmap() + geom_polygon(data=area_map, aes(x=x, y=y, group=group, color=group), etc.