# Plot a map in R - show only external borders

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, border, shapefile

My problem is with an Israel map, but I'd ask the question with US data which exists in the maps library to make it easier. I guess it should work.

I know how to control the borders of a map both on the basic plot and in ggplot. I can draw it with or without plots. However, I would like sometimes to draw only the external borders of the map, and not the borders across states (like in the drawing below).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
all_states <- map_data("state")
ggplot(all_states, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill = region)) + 
geom_polygon(color = "black", size = 1) + coord_equal(ratio=1)
```

Another question which is a bit more complex:

Let's now imagine I have a way to group specific states to 'regions'. Let's imagine we apply a category of 'south' and 'north' to every state. 
Then I would like to differentiate and be able to control 3 different type of borders - (1) the external border of the country; (2) the external border of every region; (3) the external border of each state.

Thanks!
Alan

Comment: Would my solution to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45931429/8449629) work for you?

Comment: @Z.Lin's solution is the way to go. You need to merge the polygons (states) into a single desired unit. In essence you need a second border and I know of no way to do this on the fly.

Comment: Thanks @Z.Lin, I thought about a similar solution as as a work-around, makes sense! :)

Comment: can't you do all_states <- map_data("usa") instead

Answer (score 4):

Or, use a proper shapefile:

```
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)

if (!file.exists("israel_geojson.tgz")) download.file("https://s3.amazonaws.com/osm-polygons.mapzen.com/israel_geojson.tgz", "israel_geojson.tgz")

(untar("israel_geojson.tgz", list = TRUE))
##  [1] "./israel/"                          "./israel/admin_level_2.geojson"    
##  [3] "./israel/admin_level_other.geojson" "./israel/admin_level_95.geojson"   
##  [5] "./israel/admin_level_11.geojson"    "./israel/admin_level_94.geojson"   
##  [7] "./israel/admin_level_5.geojson"     "./israel/regions.geojson"          
##  [9] "./israel/admin_level_1.geojson"     "./israel/admin_level_12.geojson"   
## [11] "./israel/admin_level_3.geojson"     "./israel/admin_level_7.geojson"    
## [13] "./israel/admin_level_0.geojson"     "./israel/admin_level_13.geojson"   
## [15] "./israel/admin_level_10.geojson"    "./israel/admin_level_6.geojson"    
## [17] "./israel/admin_level_15.geojson"    "./israel/admin_level_4.geojson"    
## [19] "./israel/admin_level_9.geojson"     "./israel/admin_level_8.geojson"
```

[According to Mapzen](https://mapzen.com/data/borders/), their admin layer 2 is the outline.

```
israel <- readOGR("./israel/admin_level_2.geojson")
israel_map <- fortify(israel)

ggplot() +
  geom_map(data=israel_map, map=israel_map, aes(long, lat, map_id=id),
           color="#2b2b2b", fill="white") +
  ggalt::coord_proj("+proj=aeqd +lat_0=31.471357089512118 +lon_0=35.189208984375") +
  ggthemes::theme_map()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As answered by [Camille](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49523256/7875328), you can use `dplyr::summarise()` to merge the borders of a shapefile. For example:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)


shp <- ... # Load your shapefile here

shp %>%
  summarise() %>%
    ggplot() +
      geom_sf()
```

Answer (score -1):

With USA it is easy

```
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
border <- map_data("usa")
```

border is a data frame so you can manipulate it ex:

```
border %>% mutate(part = ifelse(region == "main", "south", "north"))
```

Then you can plot

```
 all_states <- map_data("state")
    ggplot(all_states, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill = region)) + 
      geom_polygon(color = "red", size = 5, data = border) + coord_equal(ratio=1) +
      geom_polygon(size = 1) + coord_equal(ratio=1)
```

or you can draw whatever you want

However I doubt that there are information about israel regions in the maps package. You need to download shape files that contain the information about the israel borders. There are here http://www.gadm.org/country (Rspatial polygon). You will google out what you can do with them